# FileNotFoundError when reading tsv file to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataset, jupyter

I am trying to read a TSV file to Pandas Dataframe and I am getting an error

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'../../../../resource-datasets/stumbleupon/stumbleupon.tsv' does not exist: b'../../../../resource-datasets/stumbleupon/stumbleupon.tsv`

this is the code i am using :

```
evergreen_tsv = '../../../../resource-datasets/stumbleupon/stumbleupon.tsv'
data = pd.read_csv(evergreen_tsv, sep='\t', na_values={'is_news' : '?'}).fillna(0)
data['title'] = data.boilerplate.map(lambda x: json.loads(x).get('title', ''))
data['body'] = data.boilerplate.map(lambda x: json.loads(x).get('body', ''))
```

Comment: Have you tried using the complete file path?

Comment: Generally that error is due to your path not being correct. The absolute path should work as @AMC advised. If you want to get the relative path working, you'll need to troubleshoot more. Check `os.getcwd()` gives you what you expect for the starting point.

Comment: There are several useful snippets for troubleshooting more starting [here](http://queirozf.com/entries/working-with-files-and-the-filesystem-in-python-reference-and-examples#check-if-file-exists) and running through until the 'Delete file' section.

Comment: @Wayne i try os.path.exists(evergreen_tsv )
 ,  os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(evergreen_tsv))  ... to get the path then i change it but same error

Comment: @AMC  This dataset comes from stumbleupon, a web page

Comment: @liliy For the path, try getting it from your operating system, outside of Python.

Comment: Try putting an `r` just in front of the first quote after `evergreen_tsv = `.